# Is there a 'Cardano Naming Service' available?

Tags: wallet, metadata, cardano-address, transaction-metadata

Is there any services like ENS (Ethereum Naming Service) for Cardano available now?
If no, how difficult it is to come up with one?

Comment: I don't think anything is currently set up for domains. 

ADAHandle.com exists for human-readable wallet address mapping, and has a roadmap for extending this.
These are effectively an NFT that a wallet holds.
Adding meta-data for a URL in the future would seem trivial.

Or if you want you could put forward a proposal to https://cardano.ideascale.com/ to build something more suitable.

The current and next funding rounds have $16,000,000 each to fund project ideas.
The community votes on which ones to fund.

Answer (score 1):

[Adatar.me](https://adatar.me) is a [Project Catalyst funded projec](https://cardano.ideascale.com/c/idea/367448)t that fits the description.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier comment converted to answer to reduce duplicate answers:

I don't think anything is currently set up for domains. ADAHandle.com exists for human-readable wallet address mapping, and has a roadmap for extending this. These are effectively an NFT that a wallet holds. Adding meta-data for a URL in the future would seem trivial. Or if you want you could put forward a proposal to cardano.ideascale.com to build something more suitable. The current and next funding rounds have $16,000,000 each to fund project ideas. The community votes on which ones to fund. – MC_Brisbane 7 hours ago